# How to differentiate woods by tree density?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I'm making a game with different types of terrain. Some areas will contain woods and some of these woods will be easier or harder to traverse due to the number/density of trees. What would you call these? I'm thinking sparse and thick woods respectively but I'm sure there are better ways to name these areas.

Comment: You seem to be talking about what is more commonly and generically referred to as “forest” rather than “woods”. A “wood” can refer a particular discrete area of forest (eg: Burnham Wood, Rivington Wood) and it is possible to refer to a natural area of trees as “the woods” (particularly in fairytales and similar stories or poems), but without additional context I suspect “forest” is the word you want. Do you agree, or do you have a particular reason for choosing the word “woods” instead?

Comment: Yes, sparse and thick are good words to use for forest types. Other words include “dense” and “open”. For example, “The mountain range was surrounded by dense pine forest, thinning with increasing altitude to an open mixed forest on the high plateaus around four barren snow covered peaks.”

Comment: @OrbitalAussie I'm not very sure about the difference between woods and forest, to be honest! To give you some further context, the characters of the game move in a grid map, each square having a specific terrain (eg: plains, hills). The area of these squares is a bit arbitrary, maybe a few square kilometers each.

Comment: Forest is definitely idiomatic when discussing terrain type. For example, Worldatlas.com lists terrain common types as plateau, mountain, plain, valley, open, tundra, oasis, steppe, desert, swamp, forest, marsh, river and hill. On the other hand, the game Civilization VI uses “woods” and “rainforest” to describe features attached to small tiles of terrain as you are describing. Deciding what to use is really a choice of style.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Yeah I had Civ VI in mind when naming some of my terrain types, but in some other grid based games I found that they use "forest" instead, hence my confusion. I'll go with thick and sparse woods then. If you post your previous comment as an answer I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sparse and thick are good words to use for woods or forest types.

For example, when playing a game:

> Go south from your city because there are tiles with thick woods to
>   the north and they’ll slow you down.

Other words include “dense” and “open”. For example:

> The mountain range was surrounded by dense pine forest, thinning with
>   increasing altitude to an open mixed forest on the high plateaus
>   around four barren snow covered peaks.